# How to connect two QQuickPaintedItem based classes?

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to connect two QQuickPaintedItem based classes?

For example, in main.cpp file i declare:

```
qmlRegisterType<QlLinePlotItem>("QlLinePlotItem", 1,0, "QlLinePlotItem");
qmlRegisterType<WaterfallItem>("waterfall", 1, 0, "Waterfall");
```

I want to connect a signal from QlLinePlotItem class to a slot in WaterfallItem class (both are descendants of QQuickPaintedItem class and work fine).

Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With registering them, you have not yet created instances. What you connect are instances however.

You might now create in your QML file the instances of the two:

```
Item {
    QlLinePlotItem {
        onMySignal: wi.theSlot()
    }

    WaterfallItem {
        id: wi
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!